# Is it possible to 'stream' a variable in python?

Tags: python, stream, byte, file-handling

I don't know technically how exactly works file handling and streaming. I wonder is there anyway to stream a variable like it is being read by open() but without using open() and not from a file.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=streams).

Not from a file? Maybe using a StringIO (see the same link).